# how to Calculate this equation

Tags: calculus

I came across a calculation and i did not know what the comma in this calculation means, I was hoping someone could explain to me what it means or what it's function is.

This is the calculation:

$$S = min(T / M, 2.5) + 0.5$$

And i am referring to the comma that comes after the M variable

Thank you in advance.

Edit:
this information may shed some more light on the situation.

**LEGEND**

N   Number of Thruster Modules on a ship

F   fuel consumed per second in units

T   Thrust generated

M   Mass of the ship

S   Max speed multiplier (determines ships max speed)

$$F = N / 0.03$$

$$T = (N * 5.50)0.87 * 0.75$$

$$S = minimum(T / M, 2.5) + 0.5$$

Any decimal answers produced by these formulas should be rounded to 1 decimal place.

Comment: Without more context, it's not necessarily clear what you're talking about.

Comment: i actully found that i was missing a part.
S = minimum(T / M, 2.5) + 0.5 
this is the full calculation

Comment: @LucdeBoer, as far as I can understand, you have a minimum function of two numbers: $\frac{T}{M}$ and $2.5$. The function returns the smallest number of the two

Comment: Would you consider changing the title to something that describes your specific question, such as `What does the comma in $\min(T / M, 2.5)$ mean?` (I have arranged this so if you just cut and paste the gray-background text into your title, it will be formatted correctly.)

Answer (score 2):

Let $x$ be $\frac{T}{M}$ then the function is $f(x)=min(x,2.5)+0.5$.

The min-function can be omitted by dividing the function in two parts.

$f(x)=\begin{cases} x+0.5, \ \forall \ \  x \leq 2.5 \\ 3  \quad \ \qquad   \forall x > 2.5 \end{cases}$

with $x=\frac{T}{M}$ and $T \in \mathbb R$, $M \in \mathbb R \backslash \{0\}$.

The graph looks like the picture below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In general, the $\min$ function takes the minimum value among a list
or set of values that was given to it.

Something like $\min(x,y)$ means "the minimum value among $x$ and $y$".
Informally, people might say "$x$ or $y$, whichever is less".
The comma is merely the usual comma that separates the input values passed to
a function that takes more than one input value at a time.
So $\min(x,y)$ is a function of two values,
the one before the comma and the one after the comma.
In the case where $x = y$, the the convention is that 
$\min(x,y) = x = y$, that is, there was really only one value passed
to the function (although it was passed twice) and it is the minimum value.

In the expression $\min(T/M, 2.5)$, the values to compare are
$T/M$ and $2.5$.
So if $T/M < 2.5$, the minimum of the two values is $T/M$, but 
if $2.5 < T/M$, the minimum is $2.5$.

If $T/M = 2.5$ then you can say the result is $T/M$, and you can say
the result is $2.5$, because these are just two ways of saying
the same value in that case.